# Why does getRating() always return null even when comments do have ratings?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

So I have this code

```
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);

$activityFeed = $yt->getActivityForUser("google");
printActivityFeed($activityFeed);

function printActivityFeed($activityFeed) {
  foreach($activityFeed as $activityEntry) {
    $author = $activityEntry->getAuthorName();
    $gr = $activityEntry->getRating();
  }
}
```

Why is `$gr` always `null`/not existent even if comments got thumbs up/thumbs down?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code translates into this API call:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/events?v=2&prettyprint=true&key=AI39si6ZOCQQ0oBM_xkRpAO_sbowfEDoXQ10opTm62ZFj_2qjJtCI6GXGHCCz2bD2XObbV6uNPUx1EdbFXhwgN9-baWcKASXJg

If you take a look at the activities in that feed, none of them have to do with rating a comment. It stands to reason that the YouTube username "Google" hasn't rated any comments recently.

Comment: At http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfWb5ksi3qc&feature=g-high-rec tacoyum6 gets 158 votes up. This is the number I want to receive. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you planning to change that? If yes, when?

Comment: No. There was a longstanding request on the public issue tracker to add support for comment votes, but unfortunately it's not going to happen.